# "A line of cars swung out of the palace gates." — How will the sentence meaning change if I replace "swung" with "moved"?

Tags: meaning, difference

one of the meanings of "swing" from [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/swing_1):

> to swing - to move or make something move with a wide curved movement:
> **(1)**  *A line of cars **swung** out of the palace gates*.

I understand "swung" means some movement here.
But I can't understand what specific movement it means.
What is "a wide curved movement" as applied to (1)?

---

To better understand (1), I will introduce my variant with "moved":
**(2)**  *A line of cars **moved** out of the palace gates*.

What is the difference between (1) and (2)?

Comment: **moved** is nondescript whereas **swung** suggests the cars turned onto the roadway upon exiting the gate.

Comment: A synonym might be "pivoted" or "turned", i.e., not moving straight ahead.

Answer (score 1):

A "wide curved movement" as described in the dictionary can be imagined to be one you would see in a large processsion or parade.  Due to the typically large number of vehicles and participants marching, the swept path made when such a large group makes a turn is usually wide.

Using *moved*, which as @TimR said is nondescript would not express the scene as well as *swung* does.

Comment: Assuming that the gates opened on to a road going past the palace, the procession would have to turn right or left. As Seowjooheng says, it would need to turn in a 'wide curve'.